# Is it possible to get TouchID information and compare to a fingerprint database?

Tags: ios, fingerprint, touch-id

I know that with `LocalAuthentication`, it is easy to embed TouchID in an iOS app.

But is it possible to get the **TouchID** information and compare it to other fingerprint databases?

Comment: ,,,,
Then how you implement it,, i am also facing the same problem????
if their is any solution for it please explain ???

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From Apple doc

> Touch ID doesn't store any images of your fingerprint. It stores only
>   a mathematical representation of your fingerprint. It isn't possible
>   for someone to reverse engineer your actual fingerprint image from
>   this mathematical representation. The chip in your device also
>   includes an advanced security architecture called the Secure Enclave
>   which was developed to protect passcode and fingerprint data.
>   Fingerprint data is encrypted and protected with a key available only
>   to the Secure Enclave. Fingerprint data is used only by the Secure
>   Enclave to verify that your fingerprint matches the enrolled
>   fingerprint data. The Secure Enclave is walled off from the rest of
>   the chip and the rest of iOS. Therefore, iOS and other apps never
>   access your fingerprint data, it's never stored on Apple servers, and
>   it's never backed up to iCloud or anywhere else. **Only Touch ID uses**
>   **it, and it can't be used to match against other fingerprint databases.**

Link
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204587

Comment: @user4836394,,,,
so we can't store or record for thos who can uses the touch scan (i.e. using fingerprint) and as well we can't compare them,,, Right???
or their is any way as other iOS app used such facility in their app like Banking app, Payment app, etc.