# Is it possible to convert your iphone in a multi user finger print scanner

Tags: ios, touch-id

Does exist any method to use the Iphone touch id to recognize a user by its fingerprints. Like the normal fingerprint scanner gate does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

It is possible using the LAContext API's to recognize any of the fingerprints stored on the device. It is not currently possible to distinguish one fingerprint from another. For example, if Alice and Bob both have their fingerprints on Alice's phone, then you can code your app so that **either** Alice or Bob can use your app, but you **cannot** code your app so Alice can use it but Bob can't.

You absolutely do not have access to fingerprint data. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30159079/1050482

(It isn't clear from you question which situation you mean.)

Comment: Thanks. That was what I needed to know.
I think what I need to do is use an external fingerprint scanner and communicate to the (Iphone / Ipad) somehow.
But thanks! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after the introduction of iOS 8 it is possible to utilize TouchID to log into third party applications.  See the official sample [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014530-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

Comment: I should emphasize @Paul Cezzane's answer, which covers points that mine doesn't.

Comment: I have seen applications that let you use the touch id. But it is only used like a password. I actually was reading that apple doesn't let you access the fingerprint data.
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204587

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The data itself is not accessible.