# Is it possible to create some sort of hash/key from the user's fingerprint?

Tags: ios, touch-id

I would like to create an app, which uses a hash or key from TouchID as an ID or password, and put this hash/key into my own database.

So if the user would log in to my app from another device, with their login credentials and fingerprint, it would still recognize them.

Comment: You don't have access to the fingerprint data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, Apple doesn't provide access to fingerprint data.

And it can't be used to match against other fingerprint databases.

Read more in [an Apple support article on TouchID.](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204587)

Also see: [Is it possible to get TouchID information and compare to a fingerprint database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158984/is-it-possible-to-get-touchid-information-and-compare-to-fingerprints-database)