# Create unique id from finger print swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, fingerprint, biometrics

I want to build authentication based from the fingerprint in iPhone, if button touched fingerprint then the output should be string for authentic to store the database.

what way can I do that, simply convert the fingerprint to the string and it should be unique to everyone and stay the same when used again in the same person. thank you

Comment: fingerprint - single user authentication, once you get the success you can directly sent your data to server

Comment: @Dary i think this is not possible. Please go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158984/is-it-possible-to-get-touchid-information-and-compare-to-a-fingerprint-database

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158984/is-it-possible-to-get-touchid-information-and-compare-to-a-fingerprint-database